# Beginning with Heroku. Problem with authetication

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm noob in git/heroku etc. I work according to the tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app .

I run commands in cmd:

- heroku login
- cd node-js-getting-started
- heroku create (runned in past)
- heroku auth:token
- git push heroku master

After last command possibly window show where I put username "" and password heroku token that I get.

But after, this is displayed:

```
     C:\Users\Administrátor\node-js-getting-started>git push heroku master
    git: 'credential-managerd' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

    The most similar command is
        credential-manager
    remote: !       WARNING:
    remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
    remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
    remote: !       See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-fjord-61446.git/'
```

I'm really don't know what I should do now.

Comment: are you following this `Do not authenticate with username and password using git.`

Comment: I use username "" (empty) and password token that i get from "heroku auth:token".

Comment: I think problem is this error "git: 'credential-managerd' is not a git command."

Comment: use id password used to login in Heroku dashboard

Comment: works .........?

Comment: That's a strange error. Please [edit] your question and add your `.git/config` (you might want to edit a few things out of that for privacy reasons, but the more you can show us the better).

Comment: mehta-rohan: no.

Comment: I changed my .gitconfig and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
I changed my `.gitconfig` file from default

```
[credential]
helper = managerd
```

to

```
[credential]
helper = manager
```

and I used username "blank" instead "" (empty string) and its working.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that `managerd` isn't the default value for this setting. It's more likely to be a typo. Why are you setting `user.name` to `"blank"`?

Comment: But why not use your name? `user.name` has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: I don't know what you meaning by "user.name".  I now continue in reading Heroku tutorial. I just coded nodeJS game and now I want upload it somewhere. I'm noob in other things.

Comment: `user.name` is the Git setting to set your name (it goes with `user.email`). It's probably in the same `.gitconfig` file you reference here, and it's the only thing I can think you might mean by "username".

Comment: my .gitconfig contains only text that I added here. I'm on Windows. By username I mean it that is required by me after typing "git push heroku master"